# ORACLE - Update a value from two different columns in differente tables with a filter

Tags: sql, oracle

I'have a little question about a query.
I have to update a column from a table where there are only record of expense(integer).
I must increase the expense of 5% if the client is from a specific state, the column of the state is in a different table and the key in common is the address.

This is my query below :

```
UPDATE table 1 a
SET expense_vl = (
SELECT expense*1.05 FROM table 1
LEFT JOIN table2 b  ON b.ADDRESS_ID=a.ADDRESS_ID
WHERE description_state IN 'lollyland'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a semi-join:

```
update table_1 a
set expense_v1 = expense * 1.05
where exists (
  select null
  from table2 b
  where
    a.address_id = b.address_id and
    b.description_state = 'lollyland'
)
```

Althought I must add that it would help if you include the DDL for your table.  We're sort of guessing at which table "description" came from.

Also, when possible, include sample input for each table and desired output.  We don't need a million records, just an example that illustrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
UPDATE table1 a SET expense_vl = (SELECT expense*1.05
                                  FROM table2 b
                                  WHERE b.ADDRESS_ID=a.ADDRESS_ID)
WHERE description_state IN 'lollyland'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try with subselect:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET expense_vl =  expense*1.05
 WHERE ADDRESS_ID IN (SELECT ADDRESS_ID FROM table2 WHERE description_state IN 'lollyland')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your query like below :

```
 UPDATE table 1 A
    SET expense_vl=expense*1.05 FROM table 1
    LEFT JOIN table2 B ON B.ADDRESS_ID=A.ADDRESS_ID
    WHERE B.description_state IN 'lollyland'
```